# Android: All android activities with _MyAppState and MyApp

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I recently added flutter plugin with my android studio but after that when I open my existing android project, in each activity there consists a sub tree which contains _MyAppState and MyApp

Please help me to solve this problem.[Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHNSt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem wasted hours of my life to solve.
The easiest way was. I cut all my projects files and paste them somewhere and then after 5 seconds I paste them back again to there respective positions.

Comment: I deleted the project files and imported the same files from version control in Git and the problem solved.

Comment: Yeah! It is exactly how it can be done too. Just remove the files from that path by deleting and importing them from git or cut and pasting them again to its place.